# MongoDB installation leaving a blank folder - Windows

Tags: mongodb, installation

I have tried installing MongoDB, but it's not working. The first time, using standard installation, there wasn't even a MongoDb folder. Then I tried to install it in a folder I created (custom installation). After the installation, the folder was blank, no files.

Windows 10, 64 bits.
Downloaded here: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community

Any clues?

Comment: I'm guessing anti virus

Comment: What can I do then?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in my Windows 10, 64 bits PC .I solved by installing another version of mongoDb.
https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus-ssl?_ga=2.10188661.1735568970.1529035192-40979051.1528857771